# Is there a method to implement through data attributes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I want implement the card content in the card when expanded, I have used the help of JavaScript to implement the title, image, description ,I have used 'data-title' and 'data-type' for displaying title and image respectively which are by the working fine and when I try to implement card description by using data-desc attribute , it is displaying 'undefined'.

Anyone please help me with my code.
My code link:  https://codepen.io/Avatar_73/pen/ExyNdMK

```js
        const getCardContent = (title, type, desc) => {
            return `
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2>${title}</h2>
                    <img src="./assets/${type}.png" alt="${title}">
                    <p>${desc}</p>
                </div>
            `;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card" data-type="html" data-desc="I am HTML">
            <h2>HTML5</h2>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Add the relevant part of you code to your question. See how to create [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I have updated the specific blocks of the code, Can you please look into it now? Thanks... and if you want to run the code and check, go with Codepen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 115, you forgot to pass the desc to your `getCardContent` function

Change to:

```
const content = getCardContent(card.textContent, card.dataset.type, card.dataset.desc)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your calling method signature from

```
 getCardContent(card.textContent, card.dataset.type)
```

to

```
getCardContent(card.textContent, card.dataset.type, card.dataset.desc)
```

you are not passing the third parameter(`card.dataset.desc`) in the method thus it is rendering the value as `undefined`.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that.